# Where are symbols loaded from in a c# application

Tags: c#

I have a c# application that I got from some developers.  When the application starts to run, I see a message box telling me all the symbols it is loading.  Most are located on my machine, but there is one message that says:

```
Loading symbols from TIProData.dll from:

\\MISSIONCONTROL\Users\KLewis2\Documents\CVSRoot\C_Sharp\TIProData\Obj\Release
```

I am not connected to anything called MISSIONCONTROL.  So my question is where does my application get the information to load symbols from here?

Also, when I end the application, I see these warning messages in the Output window:

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded '\\psf\Home\Downloads\Trade-Ideas API2 New2\Trade-Ideas API2\TI_Pro_API\TI_Pro_API\TI_Pro_API\TIProDataTest\TIProDataTest\bin\Debug\TIProData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded '\\psf\Home\Downloads\Trade-Ideas API2 New2\Trade-Ideas API2\TI_Pro_API\TI_Pro_API\TI_Pro_API\TIProDataTest\TIProDataTest\bin\Debug\ServerConnection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

What is strange is that these .dll are on my machine in the exact location described in the warning message.  Why can the symbols not be loaded from here?

Comment: Can you include the warning message you mentioned containing the paths? It is possible That is a path to a shared location where the team project was housed and was worked on by the various developers. Do you get any errors? Also have you googled this?

Comment: Sorry, the path was in the message above, it just doesn't show.  The  path shown in the message was Loaded '\\psf\Home\Downloads\Trade-Ideas API2 New2\Trade-Ideas API2\TI_Pro_API\TI_Pro_API\TI_Pro_API\TIProDataTest\TIProDataTest\bin\Debug\TIProData.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.  But this .dll is on my machine in that location.  I see I don't have the PDB file but I have the dll

Comment: Your pdb file will be within the release folder but I believe that is a compiled or binary file. I would check your csprodject file(s) and see if the build information is correct for the various locations. Also checking to make sure the build references are relative and not exact should be something like `\...\...\Folder\file.dll` or `\Folder\file.dll` if the reference path has a full path referencing the remote machine that would be a problem when deployed in another environment.

Comment: There are no pdb files in my Release folder.  As I mentioned I got this from a developer.  Do you know where the reference to "\\MISSIONCONTROL\Users\KLewis2\Documents\CVSRoot\C_Sharp\TIProData\Obj\Release" is coming from?

Comment: Did you check the project files?

Comment: If you don't have the pdb file you'll want to rebuild it. Or did you get it and don't have the development files?